# Why side-by-side installation of Visual Studio editions conflicting with Entity Framework?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, visual-studio-2008

I have Visual Studio 2008 and 2010 (both Professional editions) installed. I installed Entity Framework 4.1 but after that neither VS-2008 nor VS-2010 is showing `ADO.NET Entity Data Model` in the choices when I select `Add New Item` from the `Solution Explorer`.

I tried Maintenance option of the Setup and re-installed VS 2010, but still EF is unavailable, whereas it is being listed in Windows uninstall programs list. I even tried installing `NuGet` package, but still it is unavailable.

How to resolve this conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have set your Target framework to .net 3.5 SP1+.

Also, Install Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1, since I've seen people not being able to see the `ADO.NET Entity Data Model` because they have not installed VS2008 SP1.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2010 and the Target Framework is set to .NET 4.0. Uninstalling VS from G: partition (Win 7 is installed here) and re-installing to C. Few guys suggested me that template files are lost if VS is installed other than C partition.